# How to determine if the values in a DateTime are valid?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, datetime

We have a line of code:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);
```

Which ran at 2:00 on the morning of the 29th of March 2015 in the UK. The returned value was 1:59, however because of the transition to summer time 1:59 didn't actually happen and caused exceptions further down the line.

In my opinion this is a bug in .NET however in lieu of getting a fix to the framework how can we validate that this is a valid DateTime before the following lines throw exceptions?

I'm really looking for an extension method along the lines of.

```
if(!theDate.IsValidInTimezone(TimeZoneInfo.Local))
{
  // the time is not valid
}
```

Comment: Is using a library like Noda Time an option?

Comment: You could go DateTime->Ticks->DateTime and check if this roundtrip arrives at the same point in time.

Comment: What about doing
  DateTime.NowUtc.AddMinute(-1).ToLocal(TimeZoneInfo.Local)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method could help you here.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug per se. DateTime does not care about the actual offset and if you are doing any kind of time arithmetics, you should be using UTC.

Example:

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 3, 29, 2, 59, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
    DateTime dt2 = dt.ToUniversalTime();
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(dt.AddMinutes(1).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(dt2.AddMinutes(1).ToLocalTime().ToString());
```

This will show the difference:

```
29.3.2015 2:59:00
29.3.2015 3:00:00
29.3.2015 4:00:00
```

So always handle dates in UTC.

Or you can use `DateTimeOffset`, which remembers the actual offset. And you can convert to local time:

```
    DateTimeOffset dt = new DateTime(2015, 3, 29, 2, 59, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(dt.AddMinutes(1).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(dt.AddMinutes(1).ToLocalTime().ToString());
```

Results:

```
29.3.2015 2:59:00 +02:00
29.3.2015 3:00:00 +02:00
29.3.2015 4:00:00 +03:00
```